# Shopify some of image missing found for lazy loading images

Tags: shopify, pagespeed

I am working to make a speed of shopify website.
I have added to Lazy Load script to the Shopify store.
But some of 19 images are missing found.
So how can I fix it ?

[screenshot-01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEIuB.png)
[see screenshot below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU1nR.png)

Comment: Use Google PSI or GTmetrix for better analysis.

Comment: how to add lazy loading attribute in my shopify site?

Comment: You need to 3rd party JS lib to add the lazyloading to website.